# Can a derived generic type be returned from a static method on the base abstract class?

Tags: c#, generics, static, abstract

Abstract class:

```
abstract class PersistentList<T>

public static PersistentList<T> GetInstanceOfDerivedClass()
{
    //???
}
```

Derived class:

```
public class Managers : PersistentList<Manager>
```

So, I'd like to:

```
Managers managers = Managers.GetInstanceOfDerivedClass();
```

Is that possible?

Choices are:

```
int clientID = 3;

Managers managers = Managers.For("Client", new { ClientID = clientID});

Managers managers = new Managers(new { ClientID = clientID });

Managers managers = new Managers();
managers.ClientID = clientID;
managers.Load("ForClient");
//alternatively:
Database.Load(managers, "ForClient");

//this works, however requires the above code in the constructor.
Managers managers = new Managers(clientID);

//If the static method on the abstract class (Managers.For) could determine
//the type calling, it would eliminate the need for repetitive constructors.
```

All the above are available, just trying to decide on a good technique.

Comment: I don't get it. Instead of simply instantiating the derived class, you want some static method to do that work for you? Why? What's the logic behind it? Won't be the solution equal to simple **Managers managers = new Managers()** ?

Comment: Use the Abstract Factory Pattern instead.

Comment: @walther: Use of a static factory method rather than a constructor means that the caller does not have to know the exact type of the instance to be created.  This may be useful in some cases, especially with immutable types whose initial value is set by a constructor parameter.  Consider a hypothetical abstract ImmutableMatrix type, which accepts an array as a factory-method parameter.  In some applications, it may be helpful for the factory method to examine the array and generate an `ImmutableConstantMatrix` (if all values are the same), an `ImmutableDiagonalMatrix` (if all items other...

Comment: ...than the diagonal are zero), an `ImmutableSparseMatrix` (holding its contents a `Dictionary<Point, Double>`) in case there are at least 1,000 elements and at least 90% of them are zero, or an `ImmutableBasicMatrix` if none of those conditions applies.  The base class could add additional derivatives types, which would be created based upon additional conditions, if profiling revealed that doing so would likely be helpful.  Using `myMatrix = new ImmutableBasicMatrix(myArray)` would foreclose that possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is about the simplest it'll be if you need strong typing (i.e. that the method will return `Managers`, not just `PersistentList<Manager>` when requesting a `Managers`):

```
static class PersistentList
{
    public static T GetInstanceOfDerivedClass<T, U>() where T : PersistentList<U>
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

Managers managers = PersistentList.GetInstanceOfDerivedClass<Managers, Manager>();
```

You might also do:

```
abstract class PersistentList<T, U> where T : PersistentList<T, U>
{
    public static T GetInstanceOfDerivedClass()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class Managers : PersistentList<Managers, Manager>
{
}
```

This lets you use the signature in your example, `Managers.GetInstanceOfDerivedClass()`.  I find this design pattern confusing, however, and would discourage its use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a static method.  I'm not sure why you would want to, but you can do this

```
    public abstract class PersistentList<T>
    {
        public PersistentList<T> GetInstanceOfDerivedClass()
        {
            return (PersistentList<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType());
        }
    }
```

**Usage**

```
Managers managers = (Managers)new Managers().GetInstanceOfDerivedClass();
```

Comment: Have you at least tested your solution? It won't even compile...It has nothing to do with static/nonstatic method.

Comment: Yep, now it works. However, I still don't get OP's reasons behind this. It's so ugly and completely equal to **Managers managers = new Managers()**

Comment: I hear you. I don't know when you would use it but on StackOverflow it's not always possible to know the bigger picture of why the person is asking the question.  There may be some obscure situation behind the question.

Comment: The goal is readability and conciseness.  I could implement Managers.For("Client") on Managers.  However that is repetitive across all implementations of the abstract PersistentList<T> class.

Comment: In that case, I would say that you are far better off just instantiating your object with `var managers = new Managers()`.  That is more readable and concise than `Managers managers = Managers.GetInstanceOfDerivedClass();` or any other custom method of instantiation that you could come up with.

Comment: I disagree.  The keyword "new" has specific meaning in programming but does not describe that it is a list from a database.  If using "new Managers(clientID)", each instance of PersistentList<T> must duplicate the exact 3 lines of code in every constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd situation to be in but assuming you are somehow confined to such a pattern, this is the closest thing I could come up with (still not exactly what you are trying to do):

```
abstract class PersistentList<T>
{
    public static T2 GetInstanceOfDerivedClass<T2>() where T2 : PersistentList<T>
    {
        return (T2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T2));
    }
}

class Manager { }

class Managers : PersistentList<Manager> { }
```

Usage:

```
Managers managers = PersistentList<Manager>.GetInstanceOfDerivedClass<Managers>();
```

Comment: How do you know "Managers" will be the default returning type, that you hard-code it in the base class like this? I highly doubt this will be the case... Plus, can you please elaborate on how would usage of an interface help him with this problem? Generics isn't really the problem. Maybe it's just too late for me to think today, don't know.

Comment: You are right thanks... I think I was completely misreading what they are asking for. Took another stab but this is ugly...

Answer (score 0):

One could use a pattern like you describe, but in some cases it may be useful to have the factory method be a generic method within a non-generic static class, especially if the method will take any parameters which could be used for type inference.  For example, if one had a method to create a new collection which would be initially populated from a `T[]`, it may in some cases be more convenient to use `SuperCollection<T> SuperCollection.Create<T>(T InitialValues[])` than `SuperCollection<T> SuperCollection<T>.Create(T InitialValues[])`, since the former could automatically infer the type of collection to create based upon the type of the array parameter.

Other than that, I think what you describe is a perfectly reasonable pattern in cases where the type of object which is created may depend upon various factors which might not be known at compile time.